# Simple Interest, Balance and Interest Posting Payment and Reversing a Payment

Tags: c#, sql, vb.net, math, accounting

I have written SQL code for accounting software (actually, it's Debt Collection Software) that calculates the principal and interest balance on accounts.
The accounts accrue simple interest, and when a payment is posted to the account, it's applied to the interest balance first, then the remainder to the principal balance. How much was applied to the interest and principle (and any additional left over) is stored in 3 fields for that payment (Int_Paid, Prin_Paid, Additional_Paid). Simple right?

However, what I can't figure out is if there is a simple way to handle the reversal of a payment that was previously posted and I can't figure out a way to handle a payment being posted that is back-dated.

Is there a standard for this?

What I am doing now is if there is any reversed payment or any back-dated payment then I am re-calculating everything from scratch - each and every payment ever posted to the account - all from scratch. It's the only way I feel comfortable doing it.

Maybe that IS the standard way?

Comment: The standard is not to do interest as a part of the transaction

Comment: A good idea might be to store transactions which can be applied or reversed. The current balance is not stored in a field, rather calculated by applying all the transactions to the initial balance. That way you can reverse transactions by marking them as cancelled at later time and excluding them from the transaction list.

Comment: The standard is to do what is called an event store. Then handle the interest separately. NEVER store the total.

Comment: @Aron  can you elaborate?  I do store each payment in a "Payments" table which includes columns like PmtDate, PmtAmt,  Int_Paid, Prin_Paid, Additional_Paid, etc.  We would need to store the balance in the main account table somewhere to quickly get the current balance of the account rather than needing to computer it every time the account is viewed or we send a mailer, etc.

Comment: Storing payment events in a table and summing those up to calculate the current balance is fine, but when there is interest involved and each payment may reduce the principal or interest which changes how much interested is calculated thereafter is where it seems to get real hairy.

Comment: Maybe I should clarify one more thing. Looping through the payment data in code to calculate  the balance is no problem at all. Where I am stuck is doing it simply through SQL alone. Short of using a cursor.

Comment: @JasonRoozee, is there any reason you are doing it in SQL? My experience is that SQL, like RegEx is a write only language, which is very hard to source control.

Comment: @aron - Currently I am doing it in code not SQL. The code updates the balance in the SQL database for each account so when a user views an account, or when the system generates a email, or letter for the account, the balance for the account can easily be obtained from the database. 

All ledger activity is stored in tables for each account. Each time something is posted to the account, I re-run through all transactions to calc. the new balance. Is that the best/correct way?

Comment: Or, is there is a better way since processing a very large number of transactions on each account each, each ledger item, every time time a payment is posted can be time and energy consuming.

Comment: If you must go down this route,  you can look into materialised views....

Comment: That's true, however, that doesn't answer my question. What is the standard or recommended way in order to quickly get the current balance for the account? I am not understanding how other developers do it.